# How to design a program with Qt frontend and separable backend?

Tags: c++, qt, components, parallel-processing

I want to develop a **Qt frontend** for a program which needs to be usable from a command line as well. First, I thought of solving this with a parameter (if it is set, then UI will be created, else just write on `std::out`) but I've got the feeling that **I should separate those components** and just create the program for the **backend logic** ( using plain c++ if possible ). In which case the Qt program can read, and understand the output of the backend. Still if needed the backend could be run alone writing its results on `std::out`.

What's the most elegant way to call the backend program from the frontend, **without blocking?**

My first thought on this was creating a child process and with exec, call the backend, then if the backend is finished, it should signal the frontend and block until frontend is done with reading, where reading could be done through a pipe or something like that.

**Is this a good approach? Any other tips for implementation?**

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a Qt GUI application that calls a command line executable that performs the real work? In that case you could use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocess.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has multiple features allowing for asynchronous execution:

- [The signal and slots](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)  : A more robust way of communicating than call-backs. You can use queued connection to trigger a slot later
- [Qt concurrent](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html) : Basically allow you to run some methods inside a thread-pool.
- Check this [list](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/thread-basics.html#dealing-with-asynchronous-execution)

My thoughts would be to design the back-end as an API. Specifically, in each component you need an subset of objects (maybe just one) through which all communications with external component goes. Avoid putting too much logic inside the front end and avoid writing the back-end based on visual appearance. It is a bit vague :P.

Comment: I could be wrong, but when going for threads the project needs to be compiled/run as one unit, right? What I would want to seperate my project on two programs, where the backend could be run alone, in case it would use the `std::out` writing the results of working. Maybe it was confusing to call that backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QxORM, a Qt based ORM.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would go with one of two solutions.

First the linux "everything is a file" mentality:
Create two files which the backend and frontend check on a regular basis, one where the front-end asks the backend for data, or to execute something. And one where you output the result of the query. You could use XML to have a "result" field and a "request id" field.

Secondly you could write them in a client server configuration, and for security purposes let the server bind to 127.0.0.1.

Good Luck :)